# Git tf checkin --deep command doesn't work as required

Tags: git, git-tf

I am doing migration from git to tfs, while doing checkin using git tf checkin --deep command but even with --deep the checkin will lose the info about who was the original commiter, and reassign all commits with current user executing the checkin. while doing migration i dont want to lose info about who did original checkin so can you anyone tell which command will help in this.

Thanks and Regards

Dushyant Padhya

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to keep the author since 2.0.3.1

From 2.0.3.1 [release notes](https://gittf.codeplex.com/releases/view/116074):

> ## New Features:
>
> ### Enable to use the commit author as the change set owner. With this change the '`git tf checkin --deep`' command recognizes the following new options:
>
> - `--keep-author` - Use the commit author as the change set owner when checking in deep. The commit author should be known to TFS either by his name or e-mail address. To use this option you should be either a TFS project administrator or have the "Check in other users' changes" permission.
> - `--ignore-author` - Use the the current authenticated user as the changeset owner.
> - `--user-map` - Specifies an absolute or relative path to a file providing mapping between Git repository commit authors and TFS user identities. To generate a template mapping file, run check in command with `--keep-author` option in preview mode. (default: `./USERMAP`)

Comment: The mapping is not always working for me.  I have added many users from the source repository but only some of them moved to the [mapped] section.  Several are still in [umapped] and one user I cannot add to VSTS because I believe it is a deactivated/deleted Azure AD account, so the add user process fails, saying "Aad guest invitation failed".